# ¿Cómo mostrar los productos del segundo id en adelante?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Necesito mostrar los productos a partir del segundo producto en adelante, Para captar la idea, muestro un ejemplo del diseño de la base de datos.

```
id     product
1       One
2       Two
3       there
4       Four
5       Five
```

Necesito mostrar los productos iniciando del `id -> 2` en adelante.

He tratado de está forma, pero sólo me muestra el producto del `id -> 2` y no el resto de los productos.

```
Select * from products where id = 2 and active='1' order by id ASC limit 16
```

Comment: Tenes varias formas: si la columna id es **numérica**, podrías utilizar el comparador mayor o igual `>=` en la parte de la consulta `where id >= 2`. Si tu intención es mostrar "todo lo que no es `id = 1`" podrías hacer uso de algo como `where id <> 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La clausula `LIMIT` puede ser usada para restringir el número de registros que se retornan en una consulta `SELECT`. Recibe uno o dos argumentos.

Si usamos LIMIT con un sólo argumento, estaremos seleccionando sólamente los `N` primeros elementos de nuestra tabla.

```
// Devuelve los dos primeros registros
SELECT * FROM tabla LIMIT 2
```

Por defecto el registro inicial es `0`, es decir, `0` equivale al primer registro de la tabla.

Si usamos LIMIT con dos argumentos, el primer argumento especifica el primer registro a devolver y el segundo la cantidad total de registros a devolver.

```
// Devuelve 10 registros de la tabla, empezando por el tercero e ignorando los dos primeros
SELECT * FROM tabla LIMIT 2,10
```

Si usamos como segundo parámetro de `LIMIT` un número lo suficientemente grande seleccionará todos los registros de una tabla.

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE LIMIT 1, 18446744073709551615
```

** Se recomienda el uso de `LIMIT` en conjunto con la sentencia `ORDER BY` para evitar resultados inconsistentes.*

---

Me parece que la mejor solución en este caso es la siguiente consulta porque devuelve todos los productos que están activos, desde el segundo hasta el último sin importar el ID de la tabla. Es un matiz a tener en cuenta, sobretodo si se permite eliminar registros de la tabla y el primer registro pasa a ser otro distinto al del id 1.

```
SELECT * from products WHERE active='1' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1, 18446744073709551615;
```

Comment: Esta es la manera correcta de hacerlo. Funciona incluso si los `id` no son consecutivos.

Answer (score 8):

Sí el ID es `autoincrement` *(no generado y númerico)* bastaría con obtener los elementos que sean mayores o iguales a 2 , es decir  `ID` **>=**  `2`

```
Select * from products  where id >= 2 and active='1' order by id ASC limit 16 ;
/* Otra forma sería*/
Select * from products  where id <> 1 and active='1' order by id ASC limit 16 ;
```

Comment: Solo un apunte. En la primera consulta bastaría con poner mayor que uno ( >1 )  y evitarías tener 2 evaluaciones ( >=2 ). Te dejo mis puntos.

Comment: Incluso si la columna `id` es `autoincrement` y comienza en `1`, puede no funcionar. En cualquier momento se puede eliminar el primer y segundo registro y en ese caso el primer `id` sería `3`. La respuesta correcta es la de [Matias Olivera](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83570/c%c3%b3mo-mostrar-los-productos-del-segundo-id-en-adelante#answer-83574)

Comment: @Abraham la pregunta dice claramente **productos iniciando del id 2** ojo que no dice a partir del segundo registro.Esta pensando en casos no relacionados a la pregunta. Además no deberían eliminarse jamás los registros solo se les daria  de baja.(activo o no) por lo tanto si existen en la bd. Existirán siempre

Comment: @Dev.Joel La pregunta dice "mostrar los productos a partir del segundo producto en adelante". Ademas eliminar un registro es totalmente válido y si debe hacerse o no dependerá de las necesidades del proyecto.

Comment: @Abraham para mi no  es válido. Igual sería un tema de discusión sobre opiniones. Quizá la pregunta pide los dos. Primer registro y a partir del id 2. Igual es una buena observación

Comment: @AbrahamTS Realmente yo no necesito eliminar los registros de mi base de datos para ello utilizo el active para mostrar o no ese producto.

Comment: @Dev.Joel Muy buena respuesta amigo, un +1 sumara, más los votos a favor seguro llegara casi al puntaje sobre una respuesta aceptada.

Comment: @J.Mick no hay problema, usted acepta la mejor respuesta. Igual mi respuesta ayudará a otros usuarios con el mismo problema. Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

Primero ordenamos los datos con `order by id ASC` y luego si hacemos una consulta diciendo q el `id` tiene q ser mayor e igual q 2 (`>=2`) quedando asi

```
select * from products where id >= 2 order by id ASC
```

Comment: Incluso si la columna `id` es `autoincrement` y comienza en `1`, puede no funcionar. En cualquier momento se puede eliminar el primer y segundo registro y en ese caso el primer `id` sería `3`. La respuesta correcta es la de [Matias Olivera](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83570/c%c3%b3mo-mostrar-los-productos-del-segundo-id-en-adelante#answer-83574)